# Ajax Post request from ssl to non ssl server

Tags: php, ajax, http, ssl, https

So I have written some code to execute a ajax post request to a remote server and execute ssh2 commands. The server sending the request has a valid ssl certificate, the remote server has no domain (just ip) or ssl. The response is always blocked and returned with code 500. Is there any way to by pass this?

```
function executeSSH($commandLines) {
    global $sshsshhost, $sshsshuser, $sshsshpass;

    $connection = ssh2_connect($sshsshhost, 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $sshsshuser, $sshsshpass);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($commandLines); $i++) {
        ssh2_exec($connection,  $commandLines[$i]);
    }

    ssh2_disconnect($connection);
}

if (isset($_POST['startBot'])) {
    $qport = $_POST['port'];
    executeSSH(['cd /home/botsv2/bot' . $qport . '/ && screen -d -m -S bot' . $qport . ' mono /home/botsv2/bot' . $qport . '/TS3AudioBot.exe']);
}
```

```
    $('#startBot').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#startBot,#stopBot,#restartBot,#deleteBot,#saveChanges").prop('disabled', true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true, // Also tried crossDomain = true
            dataType: "text",
            url: 'currentSite.php?uid=' + <?php echo $botID; ?>,
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                // Already tried with headers, but doesn't work
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000");
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            },
            data: {
                startBot: "true",
                port: <?php echo $qport; ?>
            },
            success: function () {
                $("#stopBot,#restartBot,#deleteBot,#saveChanges").prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Beware that your code is open to dangerous command injection, i.e. something like setting `port` to `; rm -rf /;` by a malicious client. As for answering your question: This is not possible since you are trying to do dangerous [Active mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).

Comment: Okay thank you for answering